# i want to use dynamic id and company name in my url using routes in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, url, dynamic, routes

ho can i use dynamic id and company name in url using laravel 5 , for example 
my url is http://beta.simplesign.se/12/textpress wher 12 and textpress can be dynamic  i have tried this 
Route::get('/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {

Route::controller('/'.$id.'/'.$name.'/','onlinecontractController');
});

but this shows ReflectionException in ControllerInspector.php

Answer (score 1):

Just set your route like this :

```
Route::get('{id}/{name}', ['uses' => 'YourController@show']);
```

And add a function called show atyour controller like this :

```
public function show($id, $name) {
    print_r($id . ' ' . $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes will be

```
Route::get('{id}/{name}', 'YourController@yourMethod');
```

And then your controller method will be

```
public function yourMethod($id, $name){
//now you can die and dump dynamic id and name here
dd($id, $name);
}
```